# Iterating extraction of polylines and annotations from CAD to Esri Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase, feature-class, annotation

I have successfully converted a DWG lines and annotation in a geodatabase annotation feature and polyline feature using Arcgis 10.2.2 
And now I want to construct a model builder to automate and iterate this process for my 19000 remaining dwg.
I started to build it but I am confuse with which tools to use so that the model works and names of feature doesn't get duplicated inside geodatabase.

The steps I used to convert it manually one by one is:

1-Create a file geodatabase

2-Open ArcMap and insert the annotation and the polyline layer of the Autocad file in Arcmap

3-Click on annotation layer and convert to geodatabase annotation

4-Click on polyline layer and export data to the geodatabase

5-Then from toolbox merge all the converted annotation layer in one annotation layer and do the same for the polyline layer

Now I have created a geodatabase that I want to use for this conversation and I started building my model builder but I am very confuse with which tool I can automate it, suggestion change something even to the one I already started because I am not sure if what I started is correct? Below is the screenshot of my model builder

[image: model]

Comment: Did not know about the select data tool til today. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Typically when I want to convert AutoCAD files I use the [CAD to Geodatabase tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/cad-to-geodatabase.htm). So you could use an iterator to cycle through a folder of DWG files converting them into GeoDatabase FeatureClasses. There is also an [Import CAD Annotation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/import-cad-annotation.htm) tool.

The Select Data tool is allowing access to a child object in the parent container (in your case the DWG file). It is not exporting it in any way.

Below is a model that would convert many DWG files in the a folder.

[image: Model]

You must use inline variable substitution in the output name.

Comment: Yes but it creates new feature dataset for every dwg, i want all of those to be in one feature dataset, cause i am not sure how to merge those all automatically, you have to select one by one all the annotation and use the merge tool

Comment: That is _very easily_ solved with using the collects value tool and sub-modelling, look at my answer in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221963/arc-model-iterator-reports-only-the-last-input-shapefile/221992#221992) to get an understand of how to set that up.